# Ansible EC2 metatadata options?

Tags: ansible, aws-cli

I'm trying to get Ansible EC2 to provision instances that require IMDSV2.

Through the `aws ec2 run-instances` I'm able to do it by adding `--metadata-options "HttpEndpoint=enabled,HttpTokens=required"` to my command.

I'm not seeing a matching option in the Ansible EC2 module?

I'm sure I'm missing something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything, Ansible's AWS modules often fail to support new features in a timely manner due to a combination of technical debt and lack of active developers.

In this case support for metadata options was added five days ago in [this commit](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/commit/09a853545efcb354d20cbf7b64e2b48eb58ec6bf).

Since this is not yet included in any release you would need to install the development version of this collection in order to use this feature.

Comment: Any chance you happen to know how to get the development version of collections? :D

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html#installing-a-collection-from-a-git-repository (assuming you're using a version of Ansible that supports collections and are willing to run prerelease code.)